# Распознавание рукописного текста Android

Tags: android, нейронные-сети, текст, распознавание, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека, для распознания рукописного текста с камеры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Их довольно много с разными технологиями под капотом, да и написать свою сейчас имея хорошие семплы TensorFlow, возможно, имеет ли смысл? Вам решать.

Смотрите в сторону Google Cloud Vision, ABBY  OCR, Tesseract.